# How to link option tags by name to a javascript if statement

Tags: html

I've been having some trouble coding one part of a webpage I am writing. The code looks something like this:

> form name = dropDown
>
> select
>
> option name = "normalOne" /option
>
> option name = "normalTwo" /option
>
> /select
>   /form

Then:

> if (document.dropDown.normalOne.selected == true) {
>
> window.alert("drop down menu works");
>
> }

Unfortunately, this does not work. What do I do?

Comment: Please provide your actual code which displays the issue you are describing - a [mcve].

Comment: [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49541489/edit) your question instead of putting code in a comment.

Comment: If I put HTML in the question, it does not display

Comment: Indent it by 4 spaces. You can do this by highlighting your code and clicking the `{}` button up top.

Answer (score 0):

Option elements don't have names (and the `name` attribute is not valid for them).

Deal with values instead.

```js
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", show);

function show(event) {
    const select = document.querySelector("select");
    const value = select.value;
    console.log(value);
}
```

```html
<select>
    <option value="a"> One
    <option value="b"> Two
    <option value="c"> Three
</select>

<button>Log</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
    
    <select onChange="check(this.value)">
      <option value="normalOne">normalOne</option>
      <option value="normalTwo">normalTwo</option>
    </select>
      
    </body>
    <script>
    function check(value){
    if (value === "normalOne") {
    
    window.alert("drop down menu works");
    
    }
    }
    </script>
    </html>
```